# Flex 3: Problem with Flash Player 10 Upgrade on Firefox

Tags: apache-flex, firefox, flashplayer-10, flashplayer-9

UPDATED INFO:

Hi,

I uninstalled Flash Player 10 and re-installed Flash Player 9 debug version. I also uninstalled and re-installed Firefox. Unfortunately, I'm getting the same problem. If I set Flex's browser to Safari in the preferences, then everything works fine. If I switch it to Firefox, then it blows up. My project has an image with buttons on top of it. Occasionally, Firefox will load the buttons, but they will be shifted significantly to the left. Usually Firefox loads the image and no buttons. It seems that part of my project isn't loading. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem? It's a very strange and very frustrating problem. Thank you.

---

Hi,

I've got a Flex 3 app that targets Flash Player 9. I was running it on my local machine (a mac) and it was working fine. I got a prompt from Firefox to upgrade to Flash Player 10, which I did. Now my app doesn't work properly on my local machine in Firefox. Only part of the app loads. Some buttons are missing.

In Flex 3's preferences, if I switch the browser to Safari, it works fine.

I tried clearing Firefox's cache. I tried starting Firefox in safe mode. I also put Firefox in the trash and downloaded a new version of Firefox.

I'm hesitant to use the Flash Player uninstaller, because as I understand it, it will uninstall Flashplayer on all of my browsers, including Safari. And if I have a problem reverting to Flashplayer 9, I'll be really screwed.

Could there be a problem related to the debug version vs. the regular version?

Has anyone else run into this problem? Any suggestions on how to solve it? I'd like to be able to use Firefox.

Thank you.

Comment: How about some screenshots or code?  Updating Flash b/c Firefox told you to will definitely remove your debug player.  But, even with the differences between debug and normal, What your describing is very unexpected behavior.

Comment: I upgraded without thinking about it. I wish that I hadn't hit the button. Yep, the debug version is gone. Do you think that I can simply download the debug version again? Or do I need to uninstall the regular Flash Player? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. I had the width and height of the button's VBox bound to the picture's width and height. When I changed it to a static width and height it worked. Thank you.